# distance from my location to any marker on the map, android

Tags: android

I am making android application to get nearby locations, I display the locations on the map, and if any marker is pressed, another activity will be opened, the second activity shows the info about the place, I want to display the distance between my current location and the marker. I passed the longitude and latitude from the first activity to the details activity; like this :

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PlaceDetailsActivity.class);
                        String reference = mMarkerPlaceLink.get(arg0.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("reference", reference);
                       intent.putExtra("mLatitude", mLatitude);
                        intent.putExtra("mLongitude", mLongitude);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

in the placeDetailsActivity :

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_details);

            Intent i=getIntent();

            c_lat=i.getStringExtra("mLatitude");
            c_lng=i.getStringExtra("mLongitude");

 double d_lat=Double.parseDouble(lat);
        double d_lng=Double.parseDouble(lng);
        double c_lat1 =Double.parseDouble(c_lat);
        double c_lng1=Double.parseDouble(c_lng);



        float[] results = new float[1]; 
        Location.distanceBetween(c_lat1, c_lng1, d_lat, d_lng, results);

                d=results[0];
```

I get d_lat and d_lng from :

```
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String,String> hPlaceDetails){

            String name = hPlaceDetails.get("name");
            String icon = hPlaceDetails.get("icon");
            String vicinity = hPlaceDetails.get("vicinity");

            lat = hPlaceDetails.get("lat");

            lng = hPlaceDetails.get("lng");
            String formatted_address = hPlaceDetails.get("formatted_address");
            String formatted_phone = hPlaceDetails.get("formatted_phone");
            String website = hPlaceDetails.get("website");
            String rating = hPlaceDetails.get("rating");
            String international_phone_number = hPlaceDetails.get("international_phone_number");
            String url = hPlaceDetails.get("url");
```

when I test my application, it crashes!!

Comment: what is the error message? show your logcat output.

Comment: @EmilAdz I tested it on real device since it uses Googel Maps!!

Comment: you can still see the error in your logcat output in eclipse.

Comment: @EmilAdz how could I test it on emulator?? my application crashes when I press on a marker on the map, and on emulator no map is shown!! 
any how; I will see the logCat

Comment: you can see the output of your real device in the logcat of eclipse, just filter it by your application package.

Comment: @EmilAdz I copy the .apk file to the mobile not run the application on the device, my laptop doesn't recognize my mobile when plugged in, so it won't work :(